# Traditional PHP/HTML script in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Hi I'm using wordpress installed in an amazon server and I would like to implement a php script without using any wordpress plugin.
What I already have is a wordpress page like the following:

```
 <form action="http://www.pageexample.com/upload.php/"enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="dark-matter">
```

and what it happens is that the php runs fine but I don't like its aspect, it looks like a blank page.
What I'm looking for is to make it look like any other page(same theme aspect as the rest of the page).
What do I have to do if I want to run the script fine but still have the head, bottom and menu of the theme? Is there any function which I can put inside my php script to make it happen?

I have tried editing the function.php file of my wordpress theme but it didn't work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have posted is pure HTML.

To attach php/html code to every page on your site, you can use the **wp_footer** action hook.

Add this to **functions.php** of your theme:

```
function add_before_body_ends() {
    // e.g. display html or call a php function
    echo '<form action="http://www.pageexample.com/upload.php/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="dark-matter">';
    // echo the form elements here
    echo '</form>';
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_before_body_ends' );
```

---

**As for your comment try something like the following:**

In the wordpress dashboard create a new page and call it "Upload". Then create a new file in the theme folder called "template-upload.php" and give it the following content:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Upload Template */ get_header(); ?>

    <?php 
    // specify the path to your upload.php (relative to this file)
    $path = 'dir/to/your/upload.php'

    // include the php that processes the form inputs
    include_once($path); 
    ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Afterwards head back to the Wordpress Dashboard and assign the template "Upload Template" that you've created to the "Upload" page.

Comment: I know it's pure html what I have posted, my problem is not the html form, it looks great.  I have the look poblem with the php script called upload.php, which is the action of the form. I want the upload.php script to look great not like a blank page, sorry for my poor explanation. @xphan

Comment: To use the header and the footer of the theme, you can for example create a custom page template. Please see my edited post for details.